Option on a Future and Interest Rate Effect
Suppose we have an option on a future with stock-type settlement. In "Option Volatility and Pricing" by Natenberg, at pag. 99 (2nd edition I guess), it's said that a change in the interest rate do not affect the forward price but it reduces the discounted payoff of a call option, thus its value.
Why the forward price is not affected by the interest rate change?
Please, let me know if more details are needed. Thanks.

When you say forward price, do you mean the strike of the futures contract?

No, I mean the forward price. I suppose that the strike is fixed along with the other option parameters (volatility, TTM,...) in this consideration by the author. Hope I am clear. I think it's related to the "forward price today not growing at the risk free rate". But I am not sure.

Hi Enrico - I am a little bit confused: what exactly is meant for "forward price" in this context? I thought the option was written on a future. Can you maybe help with the exact words of the phrase?

I reported the exact word of the author. I am also confused by it. I think we could use "future price" and then try to reason about the interest rate effect. What do you think? Would it be useful if I report the full author sentence? Thanks for the help.
